# Google timeline chart: column text length issue

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, timeline

I am using a Google timeline chart it's good but getting three issues in the first column :

1. Text is not showing properly, how to increase text length
2. Unable to render Html in the first column
3. verticle lines, how can I remove(see image)[image]

My code is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example2.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

dataTable.addRows([
 
  [ 'President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
  [ 'President', 'John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
  [ 'President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4) ],
  [ 'Vice President', 'John Adams', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
  [ 'Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
  [ 'Vice President', 'Aaron Burr', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1805, 2, 4)],
  [ 'Vice President', 'George Clinton', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)],
  [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Jay', new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 22)],
  [ 'Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1790, 2, 22), new Date(1793, 11, 31)],
  [ 'Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph', new Date(1794, 0, 2), new Date(1795, 7, 20)],
  [ 'Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', new Date(1795, 7, 20), new Date(1800, 4, 12)],
  [ 'Bleeding Protocol<br/><div class="assmInfoData">Access, Complement, Factor Xa, Andexxa</div>', 'Charles Lee', new Date(1800, 4, 13), new Date(1800, 5, 5)],
  [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Marshall', new Date(1800, 5, 13), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
  [ 'Account part of the REMS/emergency stock program?<br/><div class="assmInfoData">General, Obtained from account</div>', 'Levi Lincoln', new Date(1801, 2, 5), new Date(1801, 4, 1)],
  [ 'Secretary of State <br> A good state', 'James Madison', new Date(1801, 4, 2), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
  
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
</script>
<div id="example2.1" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: 1) there is not an option to increase the width of the text column 2) the chart is drawn using SVG, HTML simply will not work. if you want to change the text style, you can modify the SVG manually on the chart's ready event, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765057/5090771) 3) these could be removed manually as well, either by modifying the SVG or with CSS...